# PHP 5.6, find an explanation for seemingly unexplainable errors

Tags: php, php-5.6

someone could tell me if there is a reason why I get these PHP errors, which should not exist.

```
PHP Warning: include (xyz.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mypath/myfile.php on line 351
```

When the file clearly exists!

```
PHP Fatal error: Can not access MyClass::$myproperty in /mypath/MyClass.php on line 250
```

When the declaration exists:

```
class MyClass
{
...
    public static $myproperty = array();
...
```

I would like to emphasize that these errors are not always reported! But only once in a while. When I make a mistake writing a part of the code, the PHP fatal error should always occur, not 5 times a day from 12:22 to 12:27 and nevermore. I'm talking about a site from thousands of visits a day, I'm also talking about a .php file that is included on a regular basis in every request of any page.

I can't get any error in my pc (php 5.6 also) when I run and test the web application.

Is it possible some server problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you check file permissions and owner?

Comment: The file `xyz.php` doesn't exist - if you could provide your directory tree, that might help. Debug with `echo __DIR__;` to check where you are before you include that file.

Comment: @cornel.raiu : I did not check the permissions and owner. I ask you one thing: if there is a problem related to permissions and/or owner, then does it occurs every now and then or always? The strange thing is that it occurs sporadically. Do you understand?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I can provide everything you need. But, first, why I can't get any error in my pc (php 5.6 also) when I run and test the web application? I add this note on the text.

Comment: @boldfra23 it depends if you have smth like a cron job "playing" with the file permissions, it could only happen now and then. If you clear this possibility and there is no error on your local, I would check the server. There might be service interruptions of some sort. I am not a "server guy" so I can't give you directions on this

Comment: **DANGER**: [PHP 5.6 has gone past end of life](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). It is unsupported and does not get security updates. You should stop worrying about getting code working on it and upgrade to a supported version of PHP.

Comment: @cornel.raiu : there are about 10 different cron jobs online, however no one change any file permissions. I've built this application 100%, so I know perfectly what I've done, I'm not saying "my code is always perfect". In fact, my guess was some sort of server interruptions, but I'm not expert: do you have any suggestion, at least in terms of google searching.

Comment: **The strange thing is that it occurs sporadically** how did you read the files? are you by chance locking it? if yes, that explain the "sporadic" behavior as one request locks the file, the other then tries to read but fails.

Comment: Files are read by using the include command in PHP. Standard.

Comment: I am continuing my personal investigation, I have discovered that 403 errors are generated. I imagine that the server is able to autonomously start a temporary restriction that blocks access to files. Maybe when there is too much traffic. This is a hypothesis.
I will ask for assistance information.